# how to add image inside gridview with loop?

Tags: java, android, for-loop, gridview

my problem is i want to replace the number to something like an image but i dont know where to start.
how to replace the number to drawable? do i need to create adapter?

##edit

https://abhiandroid.com/ui/gridview - i did something like this...

but now how to make it loop ?

```
public class SelectSeatActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

GridView gridView;
int i;
String[] number = new String[36];
int[] seatImg = {R.drawable.available_img};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_select_seat);
    gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_seat);
   for(i = 0; i<number.length; i++){

    }
    SeatAdapter seatAdapter = new SeatAdapter(getApplicationContext(), seatImg);
    gridView.setAdapter(seatAdapter);
```

Comment: Hi @ben. Yes, you have to create a custom adapter to add imageview to each index and then load image in imageview. https://abhiandroid.com/ui/gridview a good tutorial for you to start.

Comment: Are you using recyclerView?

Comment: @Faisal thank you, i got it, but new question how do i loop the adapter?

Comment: @ben You don't have to loop through manually. The adapter takes care of the looping and generating the view. You just have to pass your list of drawables to the adapter. Check this section: "Example of GridView using Base Adapter in Android Studio" which gives you exact solution what you need

Comment: @Faisal i only have 1 drawable, but i want to copy with for loop...

Comment: Do you want to show it 36 times?

Comment: @Faisal yes, 36 times for 1 drawable

Comment: I'll try to post a solution for you. Give me 5 minutes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class SelectSeatActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   GridView gridView;
int i;
int[] loop = new int[36];
int seatImg = R.drawable.available_img;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_select_seat);
    gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_seat);

   for(i = 0; i<loop.length; i++){
        loop[i] = i;

    SeatAdapter seatAdapter = new SeatAdapter(getApplicationContext(), seatImg,loop);
    gridView.setAdapter(seatAdapter);
```

Now your seatAdapter should look something like this

```
public class SeatAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
Context context;
int seatImg;
int[] loop;
LayoutInflater inflter;

public SeatAdapter(Context applicationContext, int seatImg, int[] loop) {
    this.context = applicationContext;
    this.seatImg = seatImg;
    this.loop = loop;
    inflter = (LayoutInflater.from(applicationContext));
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return loop.length;
}
@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return null;
}
@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return 0;
}
    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        view = inflter.inflate(R.layout.seats, null); // inflate the layout
        ImageView icon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.seat_img); // get the reference of ImageView
        icon.setImageResource(seatImg); // set logo images
        return view;

}}
```

And layout resource activity_gridview for SeatAdapter should be something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView
android:src="@drawable/available_img"
android:layout_width="36dp"
android:layout_height="36dp"
android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
android:id="@+id/seat_img">

</ImageView>
```

Comment: yes like this..

Comment: Werre you able to fix the issue?

Comment: hm not yet.....

Comment: @ben let me know if you face issues.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using recycler view then try this.

```
 RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rvNumbers);
       
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 6));
        adapter = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(this, data);
        adapter.setClickListener(this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```